# The Painter in Chief

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

I go in through the doggy door
But out through the cat flap.
At times, I am cruel to the poor
But you'll never catch me in your traps.
At other times I am kind to all
And provide much needed relief.
I am most obvious when everything falls
And I am the painter in chief.

But in spite of all
When your games roll call
Sometimes one of you will shoot me.

Such violent behaviour
Against your very same saviour
When you wish to pass a test with ease.

So far, you have not been told my name;
You must guess it, the very same!
Isn't that why to this site you came?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this riddle is (and some answers were very close, but not quite there - the word in particular is important in the tercets):

> Breeze

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that you are:

> Air

I go in through the doggy door
But out through the cat flap.

> Air, in form of wind(moving air), can enter and exit throught a doggy door and exit through a cat flap.

At times, I am cruel to the poor

> Cold air, and strong wind can be very cruel to the poor, espetially, the ones who do begging on streets.

But you'll never catch me in your traps.

> You can't really catch and trap air. At least you can't trap all of the air

At other times I am kind to all
And provide much needed relief.

> Air in form of win can provide relief when it's really hot. Any wind makes it a bit better in these times. Also there is a saying `let me catch my breath`, when you are tired and did something really fast. In this case air also provides relief

I am most obvious when everything falls
And I am the painter in chief

> At autumn there is usually strong wind (At least where I live), and tree leaves almost all fall to the ground.
>  Also autumn is really beautifull at times. All those falling
>  leaves....
>  Also, the most obvios one is when you fall, or something falls air is always there.

I think i figured out a bit more

But in spite of all
When your games roll call
Sometimes one of you will shoot me.

> I thint there is a game called Paperball, for which you have to use the strength of your lungs, to provide the necessary force to shoot the paper ball. And using breath means using air.

The last lines are the most hard to figure out for me, but i'll take a try

> In times, when you are really irritated, or really worried about passing some exam, your breathing can too fast, too slow, you can hold your breath for long. And to pass the test with ease, you deeply breathe in and breathe out several times and you are good to go.

Comment: You are very close, I don't know what's misleading most of those lines are fairly literal. You're going to need to think outside of the box for the tercets.

Comment: @kanoo I still haven't figured out the last part. Doesn't really fit my current answer =) I am still thinking on it in my spare time. But your comment does give a bit of a hint...

Comment: Damn! headbang! I think i got it! unfortuinatelly I have no time to edit the post right now. Will edit it a bit later. rot13(Zl nafjre vf Nve)

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:

> Duck

"At other times I am kind to all, 
And provide much needed relief.":

> The rubber duck that babies play

"When your games roll call,
Sometimes one of you will shoot me.":

> The classic Shoot the Duck Game

"Such violent behaviour
Against your very same saviour
When you wish to pass a test with ease.":

> Rubber Duck Debugging

Comment: Can anyone tell me why my ans was downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps because you're picking and choosing lines to explain? Either way, I suggest finding a different answer ;)